# Working with Python caffe and library path

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Currently I am working with pycaffe and more specifically is working with [faster rcnn library](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn).

Faster rcnn has `caffe-fast-rcnn` caffe library.

I have a few caffe libraries built in my PC like [original caffe library](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), its branch like [apollocaffe](https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe) .

But in my .bashrc file, I don't export any PYTHONPATH.

```
echo $PYTHONPATH does not produce anything on the console.
```

If I do import caffe at console

```
mypc@mypc-HP-Z420-Workstation:~/Softwares/Projects/py-faster-rcnn/tools$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import caffe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named caffe
>>>
```

That means I have no python caffe in the path.

When I run `Demo.py inside tools folder` in `faster rcnn library`,
there is `import caffe`, how can I check which caffe is loaded for this import?

Then say, for this function call

```
net = caffe.Net(prototxt, caffemodel, caffe.TEST)
```

How can I trace which file is called for this function call in Python?

Is there a way to trace APIs call from one file to another file in Python?
I used pdb, but control S doesn't make to jump to next file if the API is from library.

Comment: @Shai, this isn't the only question here. In addition, in faster-RCNN case, there is a useful information here - the path is inserted explicitly in https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/tools/_init_paths.py.

Comment: @rkellerm they have separate file for the library.